# Ubuntu kyocera printers

Tags: 14.04, printing

In Ubuntu 14.04, my Kyocera P2040dn printer prints only from the user that installed the driver. How to make it print under other users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installation should work flawlessly if you follow these steps:

1. Download the [`.zip` archive for your printer model](https://cdn.kyostatics.net/dlc/de/driver/all/linux_8_1606_ecosys.-downloadcenteritem-Single-File.downloadcenteritem.tmp/Linux_8.1606_EC...P2x35~40dnw.zip) from www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com
2. Search the archive for the `.ppd` file for your model and extract it.
3. Move it to `/usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera`:

   ```
   sudo mv /path/to/"Kyocera ECOSYS P2040dn.PPD" /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/
   ```
4. Restart `cups`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart cups
   ```
5. Add the printer using your desktop environment's GUI, be careful to use the new `.ppd` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem on my FS-1020MFP and Ubuntu 20.04.

[This](https://github.com/mnorin/kyocera-ppd-installer) helps me:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mnorin/kyocera-ppd-installer/master/kyocera_ppds_installer.sh

chmod +x kyocera_ppds_installer.sh

sudo ./kyocera_ppds_installer.sh
```

And few reinstalling with `sudo systemctl restart cups`

Good luck!