# How to setup kyocera ecosys m2040dn scanner

Tags: drivers, scanner, simplescan

i have kyocera ecosys m2040dn MFD, installed the printer driver downloaded from the official website. but only printer working, unable to use the scanner, how to install the scanner driver?

Comment: Have you tried using the scanner with Simple Scan from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Yes, it showing no scanner deteced

Comment: Have you referenced the steps in this link? https://askubuntu.com/questions/953581/ubuntu-kyocera-printers It might be for an earlier version of Ubuntu to what you have but the steps should still persist.

Comment: already tried, no issue with printer, scanner only not detecting.

Comment: similar with Xsane?

Comment: Yes, no device available.

Comment: I'm working on scanner driver for eSCL/AirScan devices (Kyocera ECOSYS M2040dn is one of them) and looking for beta-testers. Please, try my project: https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan